# Need clues that an NPC is hiding financial hardship. (Sci-Fi/modern)

Tags: gm-preparation, investigation

I'm planning on running a Traveller game soon. The premise of the session is that an NPC has "stolen" his own artwork in order to get the insurance money (because it is insured for more than it's worth on the market).

The NPC is doing this because he is desperate for money at the moment (bad investments or some such). I'm trying to think of clues the PCs (PIs who are working for the man being accused of the crime) can find so they can realize the NPC is desperate for money.

So far, the only clue I know I want is financial documents that can be found in the NPC's home.

I was thinking another one could be that some of the NPC's household employees might complain about late paychecks, but I'm not sure...

Can you think of some clues? I want this to be something that the NPC is trying to hide so it can't be as obvious as overdue bills...

Comment: I'm trying to follow the [Three Clue Rule](https://thealexandrian.net/wordpress/1118/roleplaying-games/three-clue-rule)

Comment: Happy Holidays Daniel! This sort of “looking for ideas” question isn’t a good fit for our format, however, we maintain a [curated list of forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) where this type of question may work better. See our help article [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for some guidance that may help you focus this into something we can handle.

Comment: You might also want to visit our [chat] :)